# ODK collect can't GET forms from a rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, curl, rails-api, odk

I have a custom rails application to store and aggregate forms from ODK Collect. I can submit a form but when I try getting a form from the server I get no forms yet there are forms.

When I test my API endpoint from curl everything is okay since I am rendering an xml with an array of forms and content-type: text/xml. Here is the output of

```
curl --head -X GET localhost:3000/formList

HTTP/1.1 200 OK 

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Etag: W/"950d3122ec123f00905885e0e57d8f1a"

Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

X-Request-Id: d2b51a32-2a72-4735-b60a-efd7e0419b93

X-Runtime: 0.012544

Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26)

Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2015 16:57:34 GMT

Content-Length: 380

Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**curl -X GET localhost:3000/formList** --- returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<survey-xmls type="array">

  <survey-xml>

    <id type="integer">2</id>

    <survey-xml>

      <url>/uploads/survey_xml/survey_xml/2/CMS_1_.xml</url>

    </survey-xml>

    <created-at type="dateTime">2015-09-01T16:35:48+03:00</created-at>

    <updated-at type="dateTime">2015-09-01T16:35:48+03:00</updated-at>

  </survey-xml>


</survey-xmls>
```

Here is the server output when I run GET FORMS from ODK Collect.

Started GET "/formList" for ::1 at 2015-09-01 19:57:45 +0300

```
Processing by SurveyXmlsController#getforms as */*

  SurveyXml Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "survey_xmls".* FROM "survey_xmls"


Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured it out but I recently had problems with getting a custom form list to pull into ODK Collect. The one piece of information I was missing was including the OpenRosa version in the response headers.

X-OpenRosa-Version: 1

Without this ODK Collect wouldn't pull in the list but it also wouldn't get an error, which made it difficult for me. This may be obvious solution to people familiar with OpenRosa but for me I was just starting to learn all this.